# Program does not compile: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int (*)[3][3]’ to ‘int [9][3][3]’

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class `board`:

```
class board{
private:
    int data[9][3][3] = {};

public:
    board(int dataa[9][3][3]);
};

board::board(int dataa[9][3][3]){
    this->data = dataa; // error from title here!
```

I think the error might have something to do with the fact that an array is itself a pointer so it may interfere with types, but the code looks like it should work given that the constructor's argument type `dataa` is identical to `data`'s type. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not the correct way to copy this type of arrays, such built in arrays have no awareness of their size. Use `memcpy`, or simply make the arrays based on `std::array` instead of `int []`.

Comment: If you make a plain old struct which holds that 3-dimensional array, then you can pass the containing struct around.  `struct data_wrapper { int data[9][3][3]; };`

Comment: @Eljay I see. Is that a bad practice?

Comment: It's not terribly common practice.  It's a workaround to avoid pointer decay.  I'd actually use it to wrap the 9*3*3 nature of the multidimensional array to be an `int data[81];` internally, and then use x, y, z parameters to locate the cell in the flattened array `x + y*9 + z*27`, with `assert` in the accessor/mutator to make sure the indexes are in range.  ("indexes"?  "indices"?)  But that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: You can't directly assign arrays in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array parameter decays to a pointer so your [array 9 of array 3 of array 3 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int%20data%5B9%5D%5B3%5D%5B3%5D%20%3B) (= `int data[9][3][3]`) in a parameter becomes a [pointer to array 3 of array 3 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int%20%28*data%29%5B3%5D%5B3%5D%20%3B) (= `int (*data)[3][3]`).

But even if it didn't, C and C++ don't let you assign an array to an array—you need to use `memcpy` (or copy the array member by member, but `memcpy` is frequently more optimal).

```
//this->data = dataa
std::memcpy(this->data, dataa, sizeof(*dataa) * 9); 
//^the innermost dimension got lost in the decay so specify it explicitly (9)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to do with std::copy and iterators? Doing so with iterators seems to be more practical. And is using std::array any better than just a regular array?